# How to fix WordPress Fetch API 404 error?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, http-status-code-404, fetch-api, code-snippets

can you give me a hint?
When using JS Fetch API and $.post in the code snippet plugin in WordPress environment I am able to post data to PHP file and get what I need returned.

But the problem is it only works on localhost not on the live duplicated build?

I'm just getting 404 error on the live build.

Am I missing something perhaps in the header?

```
fetch("/public_html/wp-content/plugins/validator/sample_file.php", 
    {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => 
    {
    console.log(data);
```